# tidyr/dplyr: Apply custom multi-param function to rolling windows

Tags: r, tidyr, rolling-computation

I'd like to pass a rolling window of some columns a custom function, with the actual value of other columns.

Given the example data, and the example function. 
Apply `myfunc` to rolling windows, of size 3, of the variables `var1` and `var2`, and the first values of the `param1` and `param2`.

Example:
For the row `2015-07-03` the `myfunc` function is passed:

- `var1=c(1.18,1.27, 1.36)`
- `param1=3`
- `var2=c(3.55,3.82,4.09)`
- `param2=13`

The example data

```
library(dplyr)

myfunc <- function(var1, param1, var2, param2){
  c(length(var1), length(var2), param1, param2)
}

d <- data_frame(date = seq(as.Date('2015-07-01'), as.Date('2015-07-12'), by = '1 day'))
d <- d %>%
  mutate(var1   = seq(1,2, length=12), 
         var2   = seq(3,6, length=12),
         param1 = rep(seq(1,3, length=3),4),
         param2 = rep(seq(11,13, length=3),4))

>d
  # A tibble: 12 x 5
  date       param1 param2  var1  var2
<date>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
  1 2015-07-01      1     11  1     3   
2 2015-07-02      2     12  1.09  3.27
3 2015-07-03      3     13  1.18  3.55
4 2015-07-04      1     11  1.27  3.82
5 2015-07-05      2     12  1.36  4.09
6 2015-07-06      3     13  1.45  4.36
7 2015-07-07      1     11  1.55  4.64
8 2015-07-08      2     12  1.64  4.91
9 2015-07-09      3     13  1.73  5.18
10 2015-07-10      1     11  1.82  5.45
11 2015-07-11      2     12  1.91  5.73
12 2015-07-12      3     13  2     6
```

Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
date       param1 param2  res  
<date>      <dbl>  <dbl> <lst> 
1 2015-07-01      1     11  <..>     
2 2015-07-02      2     12  <..>   
3 2015-07-03      3     13  <..>   
4 2015-07-04      1     11  <..>   
5 2015-07-05      2     12  <..>   
6 2015-07-06      3     13  <..>  
7 2015-07-07      1     11  <..>   
8 2015-07-08      2     12  <..>   
9 2015-07-09      3     13  <..>  
10 2015-07-10      1     11  <..>   
11 2015-07-11      2     12  <..>   
12 2015-07-12      3     13  <..>
```

where for the row `2015-07-03` the content of `d$res` is `3,3,3,13`

Comment: Isn't `length(var1)` and `var2` always going to be 3? Is your rolling window size 3 by 1 step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea that uses the `rollapply` function from `zoo` package. I made a slight modification to your function by removing the `length` (which basically makes the function unnecessary but I will use it just for reference) since I am doing that via `rollapply`, i.e.

```
 myfunc <- function(var1, param1, var2, param2) {
     c(var1, var2, param1, param2)
 }

library(zoo)
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
 mutate(newvar1 = rollapply(var1, width = 3, FUN = length, partial = TRUE), 
        newvar2 = rollapply(var2, width = 3, FUN = length, partial = TRUE)) %>% 
 rowwise() %>% 
 mutate(res = list(myfunc(newvar1, newvar2, param1, param2)))
 #or mutate(res = list(c(newvar1, ...)))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 12 x 8
>    date        var1  var2 param1 param2 newvar1 newvar2 res      
>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <int>   <int> <list>   
>  1 2015-07-01  1     3         1     11       2       2 <dbl [4]>
>  2 2015-07-02  1.09  3.27      2     12       3       3 <dbl [4]>
>  3 2015-07-03  1.18  3.55      3     13       3       3 <dbl [4]>
>  4 2015-07-04  1.27  3.82      1     11       3       3 <dbl [4]>
>  5 2015-07-05  1.36  4.09      2     12       3       3 <dbl [4]>
>  6 2015-07-06  1.45  4.36      3     13       3       3 <dbl [4]>
>  7 2015-07-07  1.55  4.64      1     11       3       3 <dbl [4]>
>  8 2015-07-08  1.64  4.91      2     12       3       3 <dbl [4]>
>  9 2015-07-09  1.73  5.18      3     13       3       3 <dbl [4]>
> 10 2015-07-10  1.82  5.45      1     11       3       3 <dbl [4]>
> 11 2015-07-11  1.91  5.73      2     12       3       3 <dbl [4]>
> 12 2015-07-12  2     6         3     13       2       2 <dbl [4]>
> ```

where for the 3rd row,

```
d2$res[3]
#[[1]]
#[1]  3  3  3 13
```

**NOTE:** You can add a `select` statement at the end and of the pipe and remove `newvar*` columns